# How to do multiple counts in a MYSQL select query?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

```
SELECT count(item_id) as today FROM table1 
WHERE DATE(creation_date) > DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY);

SELECT count(item_id) as yesterday from table1
where DATE(creation_date) = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY);

SELECT count(item_id) year_period from table1
where creation_date > now() - interval 1 year;
```

I have the following queries, I would like to get the results returned from these queries in one row.
as shown below:

```
----------------------------------------
|today |  yesterday  | one_year_period |
----------------------------------------
|   2  |    5        |        7        |
----------------------------------------
```

I am award of a few way to accompliish this but I would like a more effecient solution to accomplish what I want.
I can accompliish what I want by using a union as seen here

```
SELECT count(item_id) as today FROM table1 
WHERE DATE(creation_date) > DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
union
SELECT count(item_id) as yesterday from table1
where DATE(creation_date) = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
union
SELECT count(item_id) year_period from table1
where creation_date > now() - interval 1 year;
```

I would like to optimize my solution so that the query is not repeated on 3 seperate occasions.

Comment: `SUM(CASE())` I think is what you are looking for.

Comment: use a case statement for the creation date

Comment: @WEI_DBA I am going to try the sum(case())

Comment: I made a modification to the query to use the SUM(CASE()) and I solved the issue that I was having.

Comment: `DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)` can be simplified to `CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY`.

Comment: If `creation_date` is of type `DATE`, don't wrap it in `DATE()`.

Comment: @RickJames the creation_date is of type datetime.

Comment: @AndreReid - Then, for performance:  `WHERE creation_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND creation_date < CURDATE()` -- By not hiding `creation_date` inside a function, you might be able to use `INDEX(creation_date)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CASE statements:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATE(creation_date) > DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) THEN 1 END) as today,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATE(creation_date) = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) THEN 1 END) AS yesterday,
    SUM(CASE WHEN creation_date > now() - interval 1 year THEN 1 END) AS year_period
FROM table1
```

Comment: You need `ELSE 0` on your `CASE`  or do like me and use `COUNT()` to ignore `NULLs`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   SUM(CASE WHEN DATE(creation_date) > DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) today,
   SUM(CASE WHEN DATE(creation_date) = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) yesterday,
   SUM(CASE WHEN date(creation_date) > now() - interval 1 year THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) last_year
FROM table1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for efficiency, do this, to avoid saying `DATE(creation_date)`, and to use `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(column)`. That way you can use an index on your `creation_date` column.

```
 SELECT count(*) as today 
   FROM table1 
  WHERE creation_date >= CURDATE()
```

And, if you have that index and use the sort of pattern I showed, something like your original query will be *far faster* than a bunch of `SUM(CASE...))` terms. Why? because MySQL can satisfy the query just from doing so-called [loose index scans. Loose index scans are astonishingly fast](http://www.arubin.org/blog/2010/11/18/loose-index-scan-vs-covered-indexes-in-mysql/).

```
SELECT count(*) as today FROM table1 
WHERE creation_date >= CURDATE()
union
SELECT count(*) as yesterday
 from table1
where creation_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
  and creation_date <  CURDATE()
union
SELECT count(*) year_period from table1
where creation_date >= CURDATE() - interval 1 year;
```